# list picker selection changed event fired 2 times automatically when page navigated

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I have list picker and it contains cities.

In my app ,I save user last pick to a text file so when user relaunch app they don't have to pick same city from list it will be fetched automatically but when SelectionChanged event fired automatically it saves city at index 0 as selected.That broke my whole point about saving user action because it saves index 0 as user action every time user start program like he didn't pick city.

Also selectionchanged fired automatically 2 times.

Code for Selection Changed:

```
private void cities_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
    ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("citycelection.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, ISF)))
    {
        SW.WriteLine(cities.SelectedIndex.ToString());
        SW.Close();
    }
}
```

xaml Code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="lpkItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}"  />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="lpkFullItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<toolkit:ListPicker  FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding lpkFullItemTemplate}" FontSize="20"
               ItemTemplate="{Binding lpkItemTemplate}" SelectionChanged="cities_SelectionChanged"  x:Name="cities" Height="80">

</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

**Add Items:**

```
 public MainPage()  
 {

   InitializeComponent();
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
    cities.Items.Add("        ");
    cities.Items.Add("Banovići");
    cities.Items.Add("Banja Luka");
    cities.Items.Add("Bihać");
    cities.Items.Add("Bijeljina");
    cities.Items.Add("Bileća");
    cities.Items.Add("Bos.Brod ");
    cities.Items.Add("Bos.Dubica ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Populate your list (cities) before you Initialize the component, assuming you are binding the cities to your view using binding. This will trigger it the first time, as the list is loaded and thus a first selection (empty) is done.

Comment: if i initizlize before componentz i get null referance exception

Comment: Oh i see, you are not using binding but directly linking to the item (x:Name='cities'). MVVM would nicely separate all of this using binding on the items and a binding on the selectedItem, but on your case i would consider just checking the SelectionChangedEventArgs and see if the e.New value is not null/empty.